# packaging java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have set up a java project in Eclipse and I want to put it in other machine, however my project has lots of dependencies in it. If I just copy and paste the project folder and add it to a different machine then it gives me a class path error and library error reference... what is the most efficient way of porting my code then with the source code to a different machine? does eclipse provides this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to create a basic project that you can 1-step copy-and-paste between machines is by setting up the project in a specific way:

1) Physically copy the dependency jars into the project folder, or a subfolder of the project folder:

[image]

2) Right click the JARs and select "Build Path" -> Add to Build Path.
[image]

This structure will let you copy the project to a new machine by simply copying the project folder.  It is not the most scalable organization, and I encourage you to explore other options as your project grows.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right Click on the java project
2. Select `export`
3. Select the `java node->runnable jar file` then press `next`
4. Select `Java launch configuartion` with which you have tested your app
5. Select the **third** radio button `Copy required into a sub folder next to generated jar`...
6. press finish

lets say you chose `c:\temp\myproject` folder for output and your jar name is `test.jar` then the selected folder will have `test.jar` and a folder called `lib` containing all the supplier jars.... also the manifest of `test.jar` will have the classpath entry containing all the supplier jar path....

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Class-Path: .
>   regx_lib/a.jar regx_lib/b.jar
>   regx_lib/c.jar regx_lib/d.jar
>   Main-Class: d.c.Main

Hope this will help....

Answer (score 1):

While not a pure eclipse solution, I like using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage the dependencies of my java applications and the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create distributions (including dependencies) for my users / customers.